# Got a malware and need help

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, hack

Someone sent me 1000$ but when I pasted my adress this happen:

- 15nTPsVp3EGk78FUGcmAyqCnFCsfv6shLb (mine)
- 15QrWeM7HcJz8haNQUtq6KU23GDSHn8xxx (hacker)

It's been 6 hours and still unconfirmed on blockchain and it's not on blockexplorer.

Is there anything i can do or sender to cancel the trade?

I've watched videos about how to double spend but I'm afraid it will help the transanction go through.

Comment: First of all do a malware scan to remove the malware. https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/

Comment: @Fyah Very smart thing to propose. If something has to be done within a few minutes with every second counting and costs you 1000 $ if you don't succeed, better do something that takes at least hours first.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean since your address has no transactions and the address of the hacker is censored but I assume that someone transferred the money to that addresses instead.

The sender can send the money someone else with a high fee. It's really important to do this as soon as possible because once the transaction is included in a block, you cannot undo it. It might be necessary to back up the wallet and re-import it because this is double spending and wallets usually prevent it so all your payments can go through and you don't try to spend more than you have (which will not work out for all payments anyway).

However, in this case you want to double spend so the first transaction doesn't go through and the second transaction does. For this, include a relatively high fee in the second transaction so it will be picked by the miners, not the one the hacker made.

Edit: I just saw that you posted this 12 hours ago, so this answer is probably too late. Sorry for your money. But it might be that the sender is trying to rip you off by sending the money to one of their own addresses and claiming they tried to send it to you. Don't pay!